# PHP the SELECT FROM WHERE col IN no working using array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to pull some data from MySQL using an Array that was fetch from a first query.
Everything's fine all the way to the implode after that, it's been a headache for me.
Can someone help me?

```
<?php

include("conect.php");

$colcod = $_POST['rubi'];

// $colcod = 'rubi';

include("config/conectar.php");
$colonias="SELECT zip FROM the_codes WHERE  coloni LIKE '%$colcod%' ORDER BY coloni";
$resultados = $asies->query($colonias);
    while ($fila = $resultados->fetch_array()){
      $codigo[]=$fila['zip'];
    }

array_pop($codigo);
$codigo = implode(', ',$codigo);
//print_r ($codigo); // <- Imprimimos para asegurarnos que todo está bien

$usuarios = "SELECT * FROM reg_temp WHERE zip IN ('".$codigo."') ";
$respuesta = $asies->query($usuarios);
while ($fila = $respuesta -> fetch_array()){
    $nombre = $fila['name'];
echo $nombre;
}
?>
```

Comment: First you use the `$connetction` object, then you use the `$asies` object to execute queries... Are both those objects valid mysql connections?

Comment: What is the error message? Clearly your first query cannot work because `table` is a reserved word and can't be used as a name unless it is in backticks. But I assume that's not the answer you're looking for? Or...? Could you post the original code instead of some mangled, typo-filled version?

Comment: Additionally you have a syntax error the second time you try call `fetch_array()`...

Comment: $asies is a connection objetc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$mycode = implode(', ',$mycode);` already converted the array in a comma separated string so you don't need to use `join` inside `IN(...)`

```
$usr = "SELECT * FROM reg_temp WHERE zip IN('".$mycode)."')";
$results = $asies->query($usr);
while ($row = $results->fetch_array())
{
    $name = $row['name'];
    echo $name;
}
```

Also notice `while ($row = $results-> fetch_arra())`, it's not right.

Comment: I've edited the code to its original version on my server, followed most all advice but, It still doesn't work.

Comment: Forgive me for the delay on the response. Thanks sheikh-heera, I was missing the slashes wrapping the content in front of the IN